# Escala de serviços por turnos em php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Pretendo criar uma escala de horários por turnos mensal.
Tenho 4 turnos:

- T.M = Turno da manhã (tem 11 auxiliares este turno, mas em cada dia 
     folgam 3)
- T.T = Turno da tarde (tem 5 auxiliares este turno, mas em cada dia
        folgam 2)
- T.I = Turno Intermédio (tem 4 auxiliares este turno, mas em cada dia
        folgam 2)
- T.N = Turno da Noite (tem 4 auxiliares este turno, mas em cada dia
        folgam 2)
- F = Folgas

No turno da manhã, tarde e intermédio o ciclo é trabalham 4 dias e folgam 1.
No turno da noite o ciclo é numa semana trabalham 2 noites e folgam 1, na semana seguinte trabalham 3 noites e folgam 1.

Pretendia criar uma tabela para cada mês que gerasse a escala de horários por turno automaticamente, mas ainda não encontrei uma forma de o fazer.

Neste momento pensei nesta lógica que vou apresentar, mas não forma a escala como eu pretendo e penso que o erro está na lógica:

```
<?php
$diasDaSemana=array(
    "segunda-feira"=>array(
        "tm"=>array(
            "ativos"=>5,
            "folgas"=>3
        ),
        "tt"=>array(
            "ativos"=>4,
            "folgas"=>1
        ),
        "tt2"=>array(
            "ativos"=>2,
            "folgas"=>2
        ),
        "tn"=>array(
            "ativos"=>1,
            "folgas"=>0
        ),
        "tr"=>array(
            "ativos"=>3,
            "folgas"=>2
        )
    ),
    "terça-feira"=>array(
        "tm"=>array(
            "ativos"=>5,
            "folgas"=>3
        ),
        "tt"=>array(
            "ativos"=>4,
            "folgas"=>1
        ),
        "tt2"=>array(
            "ativos"=>2,
            "folgas"=>2
        ),
        "tn"=>array(
            "ativos"=>1,
            "folgas"=>0
        ),
        "tr"=>array(
            "ativos"=>3,
            "folgas"=>2
        )
    ),
    "quarta-feira"=>array(
        "tm"=>array(
            "ativos"=>5,
            "folgas"=>3
        ),
        "tt"=>array(
            "ativos"=>4,
            "folgas"=>1
        ),
        "tt2"=>array(
            "ativos"=>2,
            "folgas"=>2
        ),
        "tn"=>array(
            "ativos"=>1,
            "folgas"=>0
        ),
        "tr"=>array(
            "ativos"=>3,
            "folgas"=>2
        )
    ),
    "quinta-feira"=>array(
        "tm"=>array(
            "ativos"=>5,
            "folgas"=>3
        ),
        "tt"=>array(
            "ativos"=>4,
            "folgas"=>1
        ),
        "tt2"=>array(
            "ativos"=>2,
            "folgas"=>2
        ),
        "tn"=>array(
            "ativos"=>1,
            "folgas"=>0
        ),
        "tr"=>array(
            "ativos"=>3,
            "folgas"=>2
        )
    ),
    "sexta-feira"=>array(
        "tm"=>array(
            "ativos"=>5,
            "folgas"=>3
        ),
        "tt"=>array(
            "ativos"=>4,
            "folgas"=>1
        ),
        "tt2"=>array(
            "ativos"=>2,
            "folgas"=>2
        ),
        "tn"=>array(
            "ativos"=>1,
            "folgas"=>0
        ),
        "tr"=>array(
            "ativos"=>3,
            "folgas"=>2
        )
    ),
    "sábado"=>array(
        "tm"=>array(
            "ativos"=>5,
            "folgas"=>3
        ),
        "tt"=>array(
            "ativos"=>4,
            "folgas"=>1
        ),
        "tt2"=>array(
            "ativos"=>2,
            "folgas"=>2
        ),
        "tn"=>array(
            "ativos"=>1,
            "folgas"=>0
        ),
        "tr"=>array(
            "ativos"=>3,
            "folgas"=>2
        )
    ),
    "domingo"=>array(
        "tm"=>array(
            "ativos"=>5,
            "folgas"=>3
        ),
        "tt"=>array(
            "ativos"=>4,
            "folgas"=>1
        ),
        "tt2"=>array(
            "ativos"=>2,
            "folgas"=>2
        ),
        "tn"=>array(
            "ativos"=>1,
            "folgas"=>0
        ),
        "tr"=>array(
            "ativos"=>3,
            "folgas"=>2
        )
    )
);

foreach ($diasDaSemana as $dias => $turnos) {
    foreach ($turnos as $turno => $value) {
        $limiteAtivo = $value["ativo"];
        $limiteFolga = $value["folga"];
        $selectAtivo="SELECT * FROM colaboradores WHERE turno='$turno' ORDER BY ultimaFolga ASC LIMIT $limiteAtivo";
        $selectAtivo="SELECT * FROM colaboradores WHERE turno='$turno' ORDER BY ultimaFolga DESC LIMIT $limiteFolga";
    }
}
```

Além disto criei 1 trabela no mysql:
Tabela com tipos de colaboradores:

```
CREATE TABLE `Colaboradores` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_colaborador` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ultimaFolga` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `turno` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Amigo, Para que fique um pouco mais claro, os auxiliares podem estar cadastrados em mais de um turno? Ou são exclusivos de um determinado turno?

Comment: @Irahe Kasprzykowski Em todos os turnos são auxiliares, e os auxiliares rotativos também podem fazer qualquer turno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso com um método pra criar a tabela. algo como o código abaixo pode te ajudar a resolver o problema:

```
function calculaFolga($turno, $ultimaFolga, $flagFolga){ //recebe como parâmetro a ultima folga, o turno e uma flag (booleana) para continuar calculando a folga do turno noturno 
  if($turno != 'tn'){ //caso não seja o turno noturno ele sempre vai adicionar 4 dias
    return $ultimaFolga + 4;
  }else{// sendo o turno noturno ele vai decidir com o valor da flag qual "punição" aplicar
    if($flagFolga){ // se for true ele trabalhou 2 dias, sua próxima folga será em mais três dias
      return $ultimaFolga + 3;
    }else{ // se for false ele trabalhou 3 dias e vai adicionar 4 dias para a próxima folga
      return $ultimaFolga + 4;
    }
  }
}
```

**Obs1**: repare que a função trabalha com retorno, então ela só faz o calculo e te retorna o resultado, lembre-se de colocá-la num loop para preencher a tabela.

**Obs2**: lembre-se de mudar o valor da flag no seu laço a cada vez que for utilizar o método.